# Notation confusion: Sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a sequence of sets where each set is given as $\mathcal{M} = \{m_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$. 
What would be the correct notation for the sequence of sets?

- Is $\mathcal{S} = \langle \mathcal{M}_j \mid j \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ correct?

Then out of $\mathcal{M}_j = \{m_{j,i} \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ or $\mathcal{M}_j = \{m^j_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$, which one would be appropriate?

Comment: Usually, we write either $\mathcal S = \{ \mathcal M_j \mid j \in \mathbb N \}$ or $\mathcal S =(\mathcal M_j)_{ j \in \mathbb N }$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mathcal{M}_{\color{red}n} = \{\,m_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\,\}$ in the first paragraph? -- I use $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ for the sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, so here IÄd use $(\mathcal M_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Other notations are common as well.

Comment: Hmm. That seems okay, but then what about the sets? I need to define the sets too.

Answer (score 0):

[According to set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), an ordinal $j$ is the set of all smaller ordinals, i.e.

$$j = \{i : i < j\} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, j-1\}$$

Let

$$\mathcal{S} = j \mapsto m[j]$$

where $f[A]$ denotes the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset) of $A$ under $f$. Then

\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}(j)
&= m[j] \\
&= \{m(i) : i \in j\} \\
&= \{m(i) : i < j\}
\end{align}

If you start indexing at 0 rather than 1 (which is convenient for reasons like the above), this seems to be what you want.